# Как оставлять приложение всегда активным в Android?

Tags: android

Поставил на смартфон+android несколько приложений месенджеров (skype, whatsup, telegram) и 2 разных будильника. Когда приложение активно (открыто на основном дисплее) - оно работает стабильно, если зайти в другое приложение оставив первое приложение на 'втором фоне' (не закрывая его), то второе приложение через пару часов нахождения в подобном "фоне" перестает работать (не принимает сообщений для мессенжеров и не звонит будильник).

Учитывая, что такое "засыпание" приложений начинается не сразу, а спустя пару часов, то это наводит на определенные мысли, что какой то процесс их принудительно завершает...

Как быть?

UPD: android 6.0.1, чистый.

Comment: Скорее всего система убивает, так как не хватает оперативной памяти

Comment: @danilshik 2 гига свободной оперативки на момент выключения дисплея...